# How to prove that this system of equations has no solution?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I'm looking for a way to prove that this system of equations has no solution for $A, B, C, a, b, c$ positive integers with $a, b, c$ distinct.

$$2^A * a = 3 * c + 1$$

$$2^B * b = 3 * a + 1$$

$$2^C * c = 3 * b + 1$$

If zero can be accepted, then there are solutions, for example:
$A=0$, $B=3$, $C=2$, $a=13$, $b=5$, $c=4$.

I've checked solutions using a computer program, but I don't know how to start a mathematical proof.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. I'm assuming $a,b,c,A,B,C$ are positive integers, and that you mean $a,b,c$ are distinct (the notation you've used is unclear). The first thing you might want to look at is adding the equations up and collecting terms in $a,b,c$. That quickly gives you a very restricted set of possible values for $A,B,C$.

Comment: (just to explain my point about notation, it's true that "$1 \neq 2 \neq 1$", but I suspect you would want to exclude that)

Comment: I changed the text to make it clear. And, yes, I need all a, b, and c to be distinct.

Comment: The solution as a column vector $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$ is the sum of the columns of the inverse of $\begin{bmatrix} 2^A & 0 & -3 \\ -3 & 2^B & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 2^C \end{bmatrix}$. This reveals that you will need $A+B+C \geq 5$ to have a positive solution; after that the question is just whether you can get $2^{B+C} + 3 \cdot 2^B$, $3 \cdot 2^C + 2^{A+C}$ and $3 \cdot 2^A + 2^{A+B}$ to be different numbers. That last bit seems to be the hard part.

Comment: Sorry, now I see that $a,b,c$ must *also* be integers. I'll slightly edit the OP to make it easier to not get confused in this way.

Comment: Redone my solution now. @Ian, thanks for pointing out the mistake! I'm curious, though, you said above that you found $A+B+C\ge 5$; I found that $A+B+C\le 5$. Is there a mistake somewhere? Or is it just that $A+B+C=5$?

Comment: @ChrisLewis The entries of the inverse have the same sign as $2^{A+B+C}-27$, so for $(a,b,c)$ to be positive, you must have $A+B+C>\log_2(27)$, the smallest such positive integer is $5$.

Comment: @ian ah, I see what you mean, that's awesome. So $A+B+C$ is exactly $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the equations together,
$$abc 2^{A+B+C} = (3a+1)(3b+1)(3c+1)$$

so
$$2^{A+B+C} = \left(3+\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(3+\frac{1}{b}\right)\left(3+\frac{1}{c}\right)$$

Since $a,b,c$ are distinct positive integers, the quantity on the right hand side is at most
$$\left(3+\frac{1}{1}\right)\left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{140}{3}$$

so $A+B+C \le 5$. Since $A,B,C$ are positive, there aren't many possibilities and it's easy to show these don't have integer solutions.

Comment: Why is it true that $2a=2$?

Comment: Chris, why "at least one of A,B,C must be less than 2"? I don't get it.

Comment: @CuriousAboutNumbers That part is a pretty painless proof by contradiction; if they're all $\geq 2$ then the LHS $\geq a+b+c$ but $a+b+c \geq 6$ since they're distinct positive integers. Right after that is where I get confused.

Comment: @Ian "Why is it true that $2a=2$?" Because I'm an idiot and misread my own calculation! (I mixed up $a$ and $A$) Editing now...

Comment: Had to redo that!! Multiplying the equations was the trick I needed, not adding.

Comment: Bravo, very interesting your solution!!
And more equations can be included in the system with this approach.
Do you think it is possible to figure out how to check algebraically that
140/3 is never equal to 2^(A+B+C)
and, likewise,
Is 175/3 never equal to $2^(A+B+C+D)?

Comment: Thanks! Glad I sorted out the mistake. Not sure what you're asking about here, though - $2$ to the power of a non-negative integer is always an integer, and the numbers you asked about are not.

Comment: @CuriousAboutNumbers You are missing the point of this argument a little bit; the point is that $2^{A+B+C} \leq 140/3$ (not equal). $140/3>46$, so the largest power of $2$ with that property is $32$, so $A+B+C$ can't be any bigger than 5. Then you just brute force through the four remaining possibilities: $(A,B,C)=(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,2,2)$.

Comment: @Ian If I can prove that the right-hand side (140/3, 91/2, 175/3, etc.) will never be a power of 2 then there is no solution

Comment: @CuriousAboutNumbers No, you can't, because the relationship is an inequality, not an equality. All that this argument is doing is giving an upper bound on $2^{A+B+C}$ and thus an upper bound on $A+B+C$. For values below the ensuing bound, this argument alone makes no promises that there are no solutions. For example in the context of the original problem, you still have to do brute force to analyze $(A,B,C)=(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,2,2)$.

Comment: @Ian, I'm trying to avoid brute force.
(A,B,C)=(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,2,2) because
$2^(A+B+C)<46$, that is, $2^(A+B+C)$ can be $2^3$, $2^4$ and $2^5$ (respectively 8, 16 and 32). So the right hand side would have to be equal to one of these 3 values for the system of equations to have a solution. However, and I still need to prove this, (3+1/a)(3+1/b)(3+1/c) will never be $2^n$. Thus, it would be proved, without brute force. Am I right?

Comment: @CuriousAboutNumbers If you can do that, then that would be a no-brute-force argument, but it is not what Chris Lewis is suggesting.

Comment: Yes, but his trick of multiplying the equations opened up more possibilities. I'll think about it and I'll ask a new question on the stackexchange to validate the solution. Thank you very much...